# ImportError: cannot import name replace_entities error when using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

In the past, I would create a spider using scrapy by writing
`scrapy startproject some_project`

Recently, I cloned a repository that had a spider, and now when I navigate to the correct location and type
`scrapy crawl some_spider -o output.csv -t csv`
I get a import errors:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/selector/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scrapy.selector.unified import *
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.misc import extract_regex
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 8, in <module>
    from w3lib.html import replace_entities
ImportError: cannot import name replace_entities
```

I googled around and attempted to see what is going on with `replace_entities' but I can't find any information.  Any help on why these import errors are occurring and any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess I know which repository you have cloned :) Which versions of `w3lib` and `Scrapy` does the output of `pip freeze` show? Thanks.

Comment: haha, we meet again! I have w3lib==1.5, and Scrapy==0.24.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`w3lib` is `Scrapy`'s dependency, quote from [`setup.py`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/0.24/setup.py) (version 0.24.4):

```
install_requires=[
    'Twisted>=10.0.0',
    'w3lib>=1.8.0',
    'queuelib',
    'lxml',
    'pyOpenSSL',
    'cssselect>=0.9',
    'six>=1.5.2',
],
```

As you see, `Scrapy` requires `w3lib` to be of version 1.8.0 or above.

The solution would be to upgrade `w3lib` package:

```
pip install --upgrade w3lib
```